# Save multiple selected listbox Item to database in separate row

Tags: c#

```
string listBoxValues = string.Empty;
string listBoxText = string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem item in this.branches.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        listBoxText = listBoxText + item.Text;
        listBoxValues = listBoxValues + item.Value;
    }
}
```

How to add the `text` and `value` of selected items from ListBox to a database table, inserting each selected item in a separate row.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `SQL Server` as your database, you need to use `ADO.NET` and MS SQL Server client (`System.Data.SqlClient`).

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (@field1, @field2)")
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in this.branches.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", item.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", item.Text);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace your connection string, table name, and column names as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(SQL);
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into  userbranchtbl (uId,branchId) VALUES(@uId,@branchId)", sqlcon);
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in this.branches.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branchId", item.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uId", uId);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: here is my code to add user and branch id save in a table but it not saves data in table correct me please if there i m wrong